# Qt - Slow GUI - Thread

Tags: performance, qt, user-interface, pthreads, qthread

when use pthread (or QThread with moveThread function) to read data (with mutex) GUI slows.

Why?

GUI Thread and pthread worker (or Qthread) are two different thread right?

Precise that the GUI don't read/write anything of data, so they are two process not correlated.

Why this issue?

(Above example of pthred worker, while GUI Dialog is created simple with qt Creator and live in main thread)

```
void* task_camera_notifier(void*)
{
    while(AppState::is_left_camera_in_grabbing && AppState::is_right_camera_in_grabbing)
    {
        camera_data left_data;
        SharedData::SecureAccess_get_leftCameraFrame(left_data);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You have to provide some code.

Comment: most probably you messed something with inter-thread communication. Run in with profiler and check where main thread spend most of the time, I'm pretty sure that it will turn out that it waits on some mutex or semaphore.

Comment: You should first run this without the gui, in a single-threaded test application, and verify how much time all those camera frame grabbing operations actually take. That should be the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedData::SecureAccess_get_leftCameraFrame(left_data);` seems a very heavy operation to me (possibly it needs to read in the image from the camera which can be pretty big, then copy it in the object). And then right after the data is just read in, the `left_data` goes out of scope and the image is deleted. And then again, and again. Try to include a small sleep in this while loop so that it does not eat up all system resources.

Final goal: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for yor support, my goal is to grab in one thread left and right image of a stereo camera, and in other thread (GUI) visualize data. Left and Right data are protected by a QMutex. For now, if try to create a thread for reading image, my gui (for example a dialog with more tabs) slow much

Comment: Do you really need to do this grabbing in a thread? How big is the image you try to capture?

Comment: 1280x1024. i need to create a realtime images viewer of a stereo camera (left and right)

Comment: 1280x1024x3 = 3932160 if the image is RAW RGB (3MB) which is a huge amount of data. Take it two times, that's 6MB, which is just too much. Maybe try to get a smaller preview?

Comment: i will try! Thanks for all your support!